# Parsing line continuations

Tags: unix, shell

What is the simplest way to parse line continuation characters?  This seems like such a basic action that I'm surprised there's no basic command for doing this.  'while read' and 'while read -r' loops don't do what I want, and the easiest solution I've found is the sed solution below.  Is there a way to do this with something basic like tr?

```
$ cat input
Output should be \
one line with a '\' character.
$ while read l; do echo $l; done < input
Output should be one line with a '' character.
$ while read -r l; do echo $l; done < input
Output should be \
one line with a '\' character.
$ sed '/\\$/{N; s/\\\n//;}' input
Output should be one line with a '\' character.
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\\\n//s' input
Output should be one line with a '\' character.
```

Comment: Note that the perl solution only works with a /g flag, and I'm not even sure how to modify the sed to handle multiple continuation, demonstrating the fragility of these solutions.

Comment: You'll want to make the sed replacement global: '/\\$/{N; s/\\\n//g;}'

Comment: that's because usually normal text files don't need to have a \ at the end to signify continuation. line continuation is shell related.

Comment: @ghostdog74: Or c strings, or make, or...lots of unixy stuff, really. Its just that those tools are have parsers of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *"simplest"* you mean concise and legible, I'd suggest your perl-ism with one small modification:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\\n//' /tmp/line-cont
```

No need for the possibly memory intensive *`... -0777 ...`* (whole file slurp mode) switch.

If, however, by *"simplest"* you mean not the leaving shell, this will suffice:

```
$ { while read -r LINE; do
    printf "%s" "${LINE%\\}";    # strip line-continuation, if any
    test "${LINE##*\\}" && echo; # emit newline for non-continued lines
    done; } < /tmp/input
```

(I prefer *`printf "%s" $USER_INPUT`* to *`echo $USER_INPUT`* because *echo* cannot portably be told to stop looking for switches, and *printf* is commonly a built-in anyway.)

Just tuck that in a user-defined function and never be revolted by it again.  Caution:   this latter approach will add a trailing newline to a file which lacks one.

Answer (score 0):

The regex way looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the Perl solution simply because it will likely be the most extensible if you want to add more functionality later.